# Google App Engine - Cloud Console Stackdriver trace details

Tags: java, google-app-engine, stackdriver

I'm trying to better understand the way Google's Cloud Console Stackdriver Trace shows call details and to debug some performance issues for my app.
Most requests work heavily with memcache set/get operations and I'm having some issues here, but what I don't understand is why there's a long time gap between calls. I have uploaded 2 screenshots.

[image: call @1025ms]
[image: call @5235ms]

So, as you can see, the call @1025ms took 2ms, but there's more than 4 seconds between it and the urlfetch call @5235ms.

First of all, my code is not intensive at that point (and the full requests shows about 9000ms of untraced time), and second, most similar requests that run the same code do not have these gaps (ie. repeating the request doesn't have the same behavior). But I also see this issue on other requests as well and I cannot reproduce them.

Please advise!

**EDIT:**

I have uploaded another screenshot from appstats. It is a "normal" request that usually takes a few hundred ms to run (max 1s), and also in localhost (development). I cannot manage to find anything to take the debug further. I feel like I am missing something simple, something at base level, regarding to the DOs and DO NOTs of app engine.

[image: appstats]

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware of the following common causes of such gaps ("untraced time"):

- The request is actually CPU-bound during these gaps.

  To check for this issue, go to the logs viewer
  and view the details of the affected incoming HTTP request. Note that
  there's also a convenient direct link from the trace details to the log
  entry. In the request log entry, look for the **cpu_ms** field, which states the

  > CPU milliseconds required to fulfill the request. This is the number of milliseconds spent by the CPU actually executing your application code, expressed in terms of a baseline 1.2 GHz Intel x86 CPU. If the CPU actually used is faster than the baseline, the CPU milliseconds can be larger than the actual clock time [..]. ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/logs/)).

  This metric is also available in **protoPayload.megaCycles**.

  Here's an example log entry of a slow request with substantial untraced time:

  ```
  2001:... - - [02/Mar/2017:19:20:22 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 660 - "Mozilla/5.0 ..." "example.com" ms=4966 **cpu_ms=11927** cpm_usd=7.376e-8 loading_request=1 instance=... app_engine_release=1.9.48 trace_id=...
  ```

  The **cpu_ms** field is unusally high (**11927**) for this example request, and indicates that most of the untraced time was spent in the application itself (or the runtime).

  Why is request handler using that much CPU? Typically, it's next to impossible to tell exactly where the CPU time was spent, but if you know what is supposed to happen in a given request, you can narrow it down more easily. Two common causes are:

  - It's the very first request to a newly started App Engine instance. The JVM needs to load classes and JIT-compile hot methods - this is expected to significantly impact the first request (and potentially a few more). Look for **loading_request=1** in the request log entry to check if your request was slow because of this. Consider [Configuring Warmup Requests to Improve Performance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/warmup-requests/configuring).

    Protip, in case you want to focus your investigation filter out such **loading requests** in the logs viewer, apply this advanced filter:

    ```
    protoPayload.megaCycles > 10000 and protoPayload.wasLoadingRequest=false
    ```
  - Some parts of the application code are massively slowed down by excessive use of reflection. This is specific to the App Engine Standard Environment where a security manager restricts the usage of reflection. Only mitigation is to use less reflection. Note that the App Engine serving infrastructure is constantly evolving, so this hint may be hopefully outdated sooner than later.

    If the issue is reproducible locally in the dev appserver, you can use a profiler (or maybe just jstack) to narrow it down. In some other cases, I literally had to incrementally bisect the application code, add more log statements, redeploy, etc., until the offending code was identified.
- There are actually untraced calls to backends that are not covered out of the box by Stackdriver Trace in the App Engine Standard Environment. The only example I'm aware of so far is Cloud SQL. Consider using [Google Cloud Trace for JDBC](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-trace-java-instrumentation/tree/master/jdbc) to get interactions with Cloud SQL traced, too.
- The application is multithreaded (great!) and experiences some self-inflicted synchronisation issues. Examples I've seen in the wild:

  - Application-specific synchronization forces all requests to the storage backend to be serialized (for a given App Engine instance). Nothing sticks out in the traces, except those mysterious gaps...
  - The application uses a database connection pool. The number of parallel requests exceeds the capacity of the pool (for a given App Engine instance), some requests have to wait until a connection becomes available. This is a more sophisticated variation of the previous item.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is occurring infrequently and that the actual processing times (indicated by the span lengths) are short, my suspicion is that some kind of App Engine scaling action is occurring in the background. For example, the slowdown may be caused by a new instance being added to your application. You can dig into this further by looking at the activity graph on the App Engine dashboard or by using AppStats (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204274/identify-why-google-app-engine-is-slow) SO post).

Showing App Engine events in the trace timeline view is something that we've been wanting to do for a while, as it would dramatically shorten the analysis process for situations like this.

Comment: I know that activating AppStats will have an impact on the app's performance, is this also true for Stakdriver Trace?

Comment: No - the tracing functionality on GAE is built into the language runtimes and doesn't have an appreciable performance impact on your app. It's meant to be run in production at scale, we only sample a small percentage of the requests received by each service.

Comment: Hi Morgan, I have activated appstats, but I cannot seem to find something to work with further (I have edited my post). Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately we're drifting beyond my area of expertise, and you'll need someone more familiar with App Engine assist. My guess is still that there's either an issue with the memcache calling pattern or that some GAE task (new instances coming online or the garbage collector running) is interfering.

Take a look at [this](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-appengine/157gsa1j8b/downtime-or-memcache-issue-latency-spike-up-to-5-8-times-and-memcache-write-error) thread - it looks like they had a similar issue that they were able to fix.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But can you please tell me what tools can I use in App Engine for memory leaks debug? (for ex. I used jvisualm+jmx when worked with standalone jetty servers)