# I recently deployed a "hello, word" flask app with google app engine (flexible) and it's very slow

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I followed this guide: [Quickstart for Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/hello-world). After launching the "hello, world" app to app engine (flex) I went to [project].appspot.com and noticed that it is very slow. I tried testing it in different devices and network conditions and I still have the same issue. I went to [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/trace/) and can't build a report due to a lack of traces. It is also slow in both http and https. I deployed to us-central and I am in Texas.

I have attached some logs from Logging and a snippet from Google Chrome's Dev Tools to show the slowness.

Logs from Logging:

[image]

Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images don’t show anything especially unexpected. Response time will vary depending on the location of the client and its distance to the region of the App Engine Flex instance. Responses that take an especially long time are likely due to a [cold boot](https://medium.com/google-cloud/app-engine-resident-instances-and-the-startup-time-problem-8c6587040a80).

Comment: Thank you. The distance was not the issue, I was having a problem with the cold boots.

Answer (score 0):

You probably use a free instance of app engine. Because it's free the lifespan is very short, therefor it shuts down after a short amount of time without requests. When you send a new request after some time, the instance has to set up and then process the request, which takes time. You can keep pinging the app to keep the instance alive. Similiar question is anwered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204274/identify-why-google-app-engine-is-slow).

Comment: Does app engine flex have a free tier? I'm redeploying the "Hello World" app with more instances (with more cpu/ram). Also, we have used google cloud before so I don't think I'm in the trial period.